# 3rd Monitor flickering on/off, Surface Book 3 with 2 external monitors

Tags: display, microsoft-surface, flashing

I just got a new surface book 3.  I have the surface dock with 2 external monitors extended using QGeeM USB-C to HDMI Female adapters .  The 3rd monitor (second external) keeps flickering on and off every few minutes.  I went and bought a new Anker USB-C to HDMI Female adapter thinking one of them was bad.  When using the ANKER adapter, the screen isn't flickering but I get a message that it may not be supplying sufficient power and I have the yellow warning triangle icon on my battery in the sys tray.  I'd rather have flicking than cause damage to the battery or power supply so I switched back to the QGeeM adapter for now.

I figure it's gotta be a power related issue, just not sure how to solve it.  Should I try using the DisplayPort connection? Any help is appreciated.  Here is my setup:

- Surface Book 3 15in, Windows 10
- Surface dock and power supply
- 2 Lenovo L24q-30 Monitors (24in 75Hz, HDMI and DP only)
- 2 QGeeM USB-C to HDMI Female adapters (3rd monitor flashes off/on every few minutes)
- 1 Anker USB-C to HDMI Female adapter (works but says there are power issues mentioned
  above)

Comment: what happens if you switch the cables around, is it always the same cable causing the flickering? Does it also flicker with one external monitor?

Comment: With the QGeeM adapters it's always the same 1 of the 2 that seems to cause the flicker, no matter which monitor or usb c port it's connected to.  And with the ANKER adapter, no matter which usb-c port/monitor combination, it immediately says something about not enough power and I get that warning icon on my battery.

Comment: I'm confused now...  why do you get a a power warning on your surface? the the monitor supplying your surface with power?

Comment: I only get that when I use the Anker adapter with any of the external monitors. Not sure why but it must be something with that adapter I guess. When using the QGeeM adapter i get the flickering. I've ordered another adapter and going to try that. So it'll be my 3rd brand to try, I dunno.

Comment: something fishi is going on, USB3 can be used to supply power to the laptop. If I understood you correctly, your suface "thinks" the monitor is some kind of power supply. How is it actually connected to a power supply?

Comment: Yea, I think it was just faulty adapters.  The 3rd adapter I got is now working with no issues.

Comment: glad you resolved it. I put all the relevant comments into an answer. Feel free to [accept](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you (or write your own which you can accept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the problem is always caused on the same QGeeM cable or the same monitor (or a certain combination of both).

In regards to the Anker cable USB3 can be used to supply power to the laptop. But as far as I understood this should be the case here. It's either faulty or the wrong cable.